# Prolog: how to convert string to integer?

Tags: string, integer, prolog

So as the title says - how do you convert a string into an integer?
the idea is something like this:

```
convert(String,Integer).

examples:
convert('1',1).
convert('33',33).
```

I'm using `swi prolog`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing numbers with multiple digits in Prolog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279822/parsing-numbers-with-multiple-digits-in-prolog)

Comment: @Ted Hopp: not a dupe, the other question has the specific context of DCGs. This can be done more easily. The OP has to decide whether a string or an atom is given, though.

Answer (score 16):

Use atom_number/2.
E.g:

```
  atom_number('123', X).
  X = 123.
```

Comment: Strictly, that's an atom, not a string.

Answer (score 12):

Assuming you really meant a string and not an atom, use `number_codes`.

```
?- number_codes(11, "11").
true.

?- number_codes(11, Str).
Str = [49, 49].            % ASCII/UTF-8

?- number_codes(N, "11").
N = 11.
```

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps use of `atom_codes(?Atom, ?String)` and `number_chars(?Number, ?CharList)` would do it.

Answer (score 2):

Quite an old, but there is a predicate in SWI Prolog: `number_string(N, S).`

[Docs](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=number_string/2)

```
number_string(123, S).
S = "123".
```

For those who are still looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
A simple example using Visual Prolog 10
==============================
% UNS-EPISI-LAB-IA

implement main
    open core

clauses
    run() :-
        console::write("Valor de A? "),
        A = console::readLine(),
        console::write("Valor de B? "),
        B = console::readLine(),
        Areal = toTerm(real, A),
        Breal = toTerm(real, B),
        console::write("A + B = ", Areal + Breal),
        _ = console::readChar().

end implement main

goal
    console::runUtf8(main::run).
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Good solution, but I think it isn't quite relevant, because OP explicitly asked for SWI-Prolog solution.

Answer (score -1):

in Visual Prolog convert:

```
X=toTerm(real,H).
```

real/integer/unsigned...