# How to change string to integer

Tags: prolog

How can I change a string input to integer-
for example-

```
read_line_to_codes(user_input,L),
atom_codes(C,L).
```

In this `C` is storing a string.Suppose the user entered `18`.So I want to use this `18` as an integer so that I can use operations like `>=` with `C`.Is this possible in Prolog?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prolog: how to convert string to integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782007/prolog-how-to-convert-string-to-integer)

Answer (score 0):

Prolog datatypes don't include 'strings'. SWI-prolog added it recently, but you can stay on ISO safety lane with [number_codes](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=number_codes/2)

Answer (score -1):

You can forcefully assigned an int datatype to the user input, you are letting the JVM know that you know what you are doing and this will let the program compile in case if the int data type is smaller than the user input string size. Here is an example code to help you.

```
public class stringToInt{

  public static void main(String []args){

    string C = 18; //User input, make sure to use the scanner class to get the user input value
    int int_C = (int) C;

    /**Your new value is now in int datatype and you can go ahead and use int_C for your arithmetic 
            opreation **/
  }

}
```

Comment: Your answer is out of scope - this is about [tag:prolog]

Comment: I was asking about prolog not java

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding. Please disregard then